# Error in Linux CodeBlocks while compile "../lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to 'cudaHostRegister'

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, codeblocks

Previously I ran my complete compile program and it works and run properly but after few weeks I try to run this program and it come out with the error from *`libopencv_core.so`*: undefined reference to `cudaHostRegister` and etc.

> /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaHostRegister'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaStreamDestroy'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaStreamWaitEvent'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaGetDeviceCount'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaMemset2D'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaFree'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaGetDeviceProperties'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaStreamQuery'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaEventSynchronize'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaSetupArgument'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaGetDevice'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`__cudaRegisterFunction'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaEventQuery'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaEventRecord'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaMemset2DAsync'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaDriverGetVersion'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaEventElapsedTime'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaStreamCreate'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaFreeHost'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaConfigureCall'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaEventDestroy'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaHostUnregister'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaRuntimeGetVersion'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaMemcpy2D'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaStreamAddCallback'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaEventCreateWithFlags'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaMemcpy2DAsync'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaHostGetDevicePointer'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaSetDevice'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaMemGetInfo'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaDeviceSynchronize'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaLaunch'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `__cudaUnregisterFatBinary'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaStreamSynchronize'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaHostAlloc'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`__cudaRegisterFatBinary'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaMallocPitch'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaMalloc'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `__cudaRegisterVar'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaGetLastError'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to `cudaGetErrorString'
>   /media/rnd/4F3D93242E986B7F/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_core.so: undefined reference to`cudaDeviceReset'

Comment: You're not running the program. These are linker errors. You get them at link time. Not runtime.

Comment: you should provide your makefile or compile flags